# ToscaWidgets2 Capture Data from GrowingGridLayout

Tags: python, forms, turbogears2

Currently working on a project with `TurboGears2` and `ToscaWidgets2`. I have a form setup with a few static fields, name, date, and point of contact information. Inside this form I have added a sub form where the user can dynamically add numerous entries in a `GrowingGridLayout`. The form, its layout, and submitting information is all well and good but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to capture the information from the `GrowingGridLayout` once it's passed on for saving. Guess the main points are, how do I know how many entries were included in the form?

Included the code for the form:

```
class OnrampForm(twf.Form):
    title = "Onramp Submission Form"

    class child(twd.CustomisedTableForm):
        onramp_name = twf.TextField(validator=twc.Required)

        class Destinations (twd.GrowingGridLayout):
            environment = twf.SingleSelectField(label='Environment', validator=twc.Validator(required=True), options=[<OPTIONS>])
            location = twf.SingleSelectField(validator=twc.Required, label='Location', options=[<OPTIONS>])
            jms_type = twf.SingleSelectField(label='JMS Type', validator=twc.Validator(required=True), options=[<OPTIONS>])
            subscription_type = twf.SingleSelectField(label='Subscription Type', validator=twc.Validator(required=True), options=[<OPTIONS>])

        onramp_status = twf.SingleSelectField(prompt_text='Status', options=['Initial Release', 'Update'], validator=twc.Required)
        current_date = datetime.date.today()
        need_by_date = twd.CalendarDatePicker(validators=[twc.Required, twc.DateTimeValidator])
        need_by_date.default = current_date + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        organization = twf.TextField(validator=twc.Required)
        poc_name = twf.TextField(validator=twc.Required)
        poc_email = twf.EmailField(validator=twc.EmailValidator)
        poc_phone = twf.TextField(validator=twc.Required)
        poc_address = twf.TextField()
        poc_city = twf.TextField()
        poc_state = twf.TextField()
        onramp_form = twf.FileField()
        submit = twf.SubmitButton(value="Submit")

    action = "/print_args"
    submit = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you controller `@validate`s against the form you should get the data into the `Destination` parameter which should be a list of dictionaries.

Also I just noticed you have two nested forms, that's something that might confuse TW2 pretty much. What you wanted to do is probably have `OnrampForm` inherit `CustomisedForm` and then have `child` inherit `TableLayout`. See http://turbogears.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/TwForms.html#displaying-forms

PS: note that `need_by_date.default = current_date + datetime.timedelta(days=30)` will always return 30 days from when the server started as you are actually storing a `current_date = datetime.date.today()` class variable that gets computed when the module is imported and no more.

You should use `default = Deferred(lambda: datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=30))` to achieve that